# Deserialize JSON to nested classes with ReactiveProperty fields

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm calling an API endpoint that return me a JSON some data and I need to deserialize it into classes and nested classes that may contains ReactiveProperty fields ( a type coming from UniRx library which is a reimplemntation of Reactive extensions for Unity3D ).

I'm new to C#, I tried some things, but I can't achieve it the way i want.

Here is the json returned by my Api ( in reality there are more data but this example will suffice ) :

```
   "user": {
        "id": "87f2ae6e-af99-4f8e-9d69-08de6ad6baf8",
        "username": "test",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "money": 800,
        "morale": 100,
        "health": 100,
        "credits": 15,
        "energy": 100,
        "banned_at": null,
        "last_connection": null,
        "officers": [
            {
                "id": "2b72d9d4-635c-4b32-9575-5df49f566e93",
                "name": "David Le Salmon",
                "is_available": true,
                "age": 42,
                "condition": 100,
                "user_id": "87f2ae6e-af99-4f8e-9d69-08de6ad6baf8"
            },
            {
                "id": "ebc4074c-7b94-4ea3-96d9-f80608972afa",
                "name": "Philippe Mercier",
                "is_available": true,
                "age": 34,
                "condition": 100,
                "user_id": "87f2ae6e-af99-4f8e-9d69-08de6ad6baf8"
            },
            {
                "id": "edba67b5-9053-4fd6-b64e-6b85f4d0cc25",
                "name": "Raymond Wagner-Berthelot",
                "is_available": true,
                "age": 55,
                "condition": 100,
                "user_id": "87f2ae6e-af99-4f8e-9d69-08de6ad6baf8"
            }
        ],
        "vehicles": [
            {
                "id": "3161d274-ed2a-491b-8515-beb7da9bfd29",
                "mileage": 0,
                "health": 100,
                "level": 3,
                "equipment_level": 4,
                "vehicle_prefab_id": "14e8d96f-0e85-40ad-b01b-5f00a37b1108"
            },
            {
                "id": "ff984c79-4511-4ade-92d1-9bf6899a243c",
                "mileage": 0,
                "health": 100,
                "level": 4,
                "equipment_level": 4,
                "vehicle_prefab_id": "14e8d96f-0e85-40ad-b01b-5f00a37b1108"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I defined some classes like this :

```
[Serializable]
public class AppState {
    public User user = new User();
}
```

```
[Serializable]
public class User {
    public string username;
    public string email;
    public ReactiveProperty<int> money = new ReactiveProperty<int>();
    public ReactiveProperty<int> morale = new ReactiveProperty<int>();
    public ReactiveProperty<int> health = new ReactiveProperty<int>();
    public ReactiveProperty<int> energy = new ReactiveProperty<int>();
    public List<Officer> officers = new List<Officer[]>();
    public List<Vehicles> vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
}
```

`Officer` and `Vehicle` are defined in the same way, some fields are ReactiveProperty, some not.

And here how I tried to deserialize :

```
RestClient.Get("/getAppState").Then(response => {
    var stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppState>(response.Text);
})
```

This code throws this error :

```
Could not cast or convert from System.String to UniRx.ReactiveProperty
```

I found something that "work", I assigned all ReactiveProperty fields manually, but it's really tedious.

Is there a way to do this in C#?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! what is a `ReactiveProperty`? Why don't you simply use `int`?

Comment: Like I said, it's a type coming from UniRx ( https://github.com/neuecc/UniRx ) which is a library for Unity that reimplement .NET reactive extensions. It allows me to be notified when this value change and update my UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the Reactive property fields NonSerializable.

Make new serializable String fields.

Deserialize the JSON.

Add some functions to your class(es) that cast the string representations into your ReactiveProperty variables.

Call those functions after you desierialize your JSON.

Note:  I am unfamiliar with ReactiveProperty, you'll need to investigate that library to find the best way of casting a string into those objects.

Comment: Thanks, it would work, I find it's also tedious ( i need to define two fields for all reactive properties ) but it seems like I don't have other choice here.